# What do eigenvectors and eigenvalues do in rotation operations?

Tags: rotations

There's some material briefly mentioned the eigenvectors and eigenvalues when it comes to rotation matrices.

Can someone give me a neat explanation for what eigenvectors and eigenvalues do in rotation operations?

Comment: You probably need to be more specific here.  Do you mean real eigenvalues or complex ones?

Answer (score 0):

In $\Bbb R^2$ a rotation matrix ($\neq$ identity and reflection) does not have any eigenvectors/eigenvalues in $\Bbb R$, because there is no direction, which is fixed by rotation.

In $\Bbb R^3$ a rotation matrix has the eigenvalue 1 and the corresponding eigenvector spans the axis of rotation. Again there are (up to the exceptions above) no more eigenvalues/eigenvectors since the linear transformation restricts to a rotation on the remaining two dimensional subspace.

In $\Bbb R^n$ one (afaik) usually does not speak of rotations, because there are not really axes of rotation any longer.

Comment: "*In $\Bbb R^2$ a rotation matrix does not have any eigenvectors/eigenvalues in $\Bbb R$"* ... with some exceptions as well in higher dimensions.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe right, I removed identity and reflection. What do you mean with higher dimension in $\Bbb R^2$?